# What is a Shifted Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series inaugurated by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with his original [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a certain rule, I call it a Shifted Word™.

Below are some examples which can be used to uncover the rule.

[image: Shifted Words™]

**Note: "YEWS" should be "YAWS"**

Here it is in CSV.

```
Shifted Words™,Not Shifted Words™
GLUE,TAPE
YAWS,SICK
VIEW,SIGHT
CLAW,HANDS
RUB,DOUSE
OUR,YOUR
RUN,WALK
LOO,BATHROOM
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think...

> A Shifted Word™ is a word that can form a new word by utilizing a QWERTY keyboard and shifting right one key (P, L, and M shift around the keyboard to Q, A, and Z respectively).

So...

- GLUE = HAIR
- YAWS = USED
- VIEW = BORE
- CLAW = VASE
- RUB = TIN
- OUR = PIT
- RUN = TIM
- LOO = APP

Comment: Nice! You even caught my error!